# Image hue modification in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image and i want to modify the hue of that particular image to specific value.
I know rgb to hsl and hsl to rgb conversion mathematical formula but I am not being able to implement this thing into c#.

Following is the pseudo:

```
for(x=0;x<image_width;x++)
{
  for(y=0;y<image_height;y++)
  {
    Color oldColor=GetColorFromPixel(x,y);
    Color newColor=ModifyHue(oldColor);
    SetColorPixel(x,y,newColor);    
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want the algorithm in C# look at [this](http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm). Check if this match with what [wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB)...

Answer (score 6):

Due to the fact, that the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14w97wkc.aspx) structure already has a [`GetHue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.gethue.aspx), [`GetSaturation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getsaturation.aspx) and [`GetBrightness()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness.aspx) it would be nice to also construct a color from these values. So i found the following code somewhere on the net a while ago (currently can't find it again, but it was from a Microsoft guy blog and he also had a test that steps through all [`KnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx)).

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a Color from alpha, hue, saturation and brightness.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="alpha">The alpha channel value.</param>
/// <param name="hue">The hue value.</param>
/// <param name="saturation">The saturation value.</param>
/// <param name="brightness">The brightness value.</param>
/// <returns>A Color with the given values.</returns>
public static Color FromAhsb(int alpha, float hue, float saturation, float brightness)
{

    if (0 > alpha || 255 < alpha)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("alpha", alpha,
          "Value must be within a range of 0 - 255.");
    }
    if (0f > hue || 360f < hue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("hue", hue,
          "Value must be within a range of 0 - 360.");
    }
    if (0f > saturation || 1f < saturation)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("saturation", saturation,
          "Value must be within a range of 0 - 1.");
    }
    if (0f > brightness || 1f < brightness)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("brightness", brightness,
          "Value must be within a range of 0 - 1.");
    }

    if (0 == saturation)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(alpha, Convert.ToInt32(brightness * 255),
          Convert.ToInt32(brightness * 255), Convert.ToInt32(brightness * 255));
    }

    float fMax, fMid, fMin;
    int iSextant, iMax, iMid, iMin;

    if (0.5 < brightness)
    {
        fMax = brightness - (brightness * saturation) + saturation;
        fMin = brightness + (brightness * saturation) - saturation;
    }
    else
    {
        fMax = brightness + (brightness * saturation);
        fMin = brightness - (brightness * saturation);
    }

    iSextant = (int)Math.Floor(hue / 60f);
    if (300f <= hue)
    {
        hue -= 360f;
    }
    hue /= 60f;
    hue -= 2f * (float)Math.Floor(((iSextant + 1f) % 6f) / 2f);
    if (0 == iSextant % 2)
    {
        fMid = hue * (fMax - fMin) + fMin;
    }
    else
    {
        fMid = fMin - hue * (fMax - fMin);
    }

    iMax = Convert.ToInt32(fMax * 255);
    iMid = Convert.ToInt32(fMid * 255);
    iMin = Convert.ToInt32(fMin * 255);

    switch (iSextant)
    {
        case 1:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMid, iMax, iMin);
        case 2:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMin, iMax, iMid);
        case 3:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMin, iMid, iMax);
        case 4:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMid, iMin, iMax);
        case 5:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMax, iMin, iMid);
        default:
            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, iMax, iMid, iMin);
    }
}
```

With this function you are able to work within the HSB (or HSV) color presentation **not** within the HSL presentation. For further informations about their differences take a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to try out or performance is not critical, the easist way is to use the `Bitmap.GetPixel` and `Bitmap.SetPixel` methods:

```
var bm = new Bitmap(filename);
for(int x=0;x<bm.Width;x++)
{
  for(y=0;y<bm.Height;y++)
  {
    Color oldColor=bm.GetPixel(x,y);
    Color newColor=ModifyHue(oldColor);
    bm.SetPixel(x,y,newColor);    
  }
}
```

If you want more performant operation, you should look at the `Bitmap.LockBits` method which fixes the entire bitmap on a memory location and lets you modify this memory directly.