# Color Table Algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I've been searching for just over a week now on how to create something like this.

[image]

I have the code and for loops to create each Panel by X, and Y coords and everything. Each Panel is part of an array and starts at 0 at top left and ends at 90 at top right, but I don't care how its done as long as its done and its panels and works. The colors don't need to be the same but something similar so that I can have a fullscreen color picker. If someone knows some code to take one specific color and make it brighter ten times to set the panels backColor, using Color.FromARGB or just the Color class, to then please help me out. Thank you.

(This is a app I'm making for windows tablet and is touchscreen. The purpose of the app is to be fullscreen and not reviele that its a windows tablet, There for I have to make the color picker myself and cannot use the built in color dialog.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also I'm not sure what you mean with making a color 10x brighter. Maybe you should take a look at the HSL color model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model#HSV_and_HSL_representations)?

Comment: An alternative to color conversion is to use a multicolor LinearGradientBrush and feed it with the corner colors..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For best control I suggest using a color calculation function.

[image]

There are many out there; here is one I use:

```
Color HsvToRgb(double h, double S, double V)
{
    /// Convert HSV to RGB
    /// h is from 0d - 360d
    /// s,v values are 0d - 1d
    /// r,g,b values are 0 - 255

    int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
    double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

    value = value * 255;
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - saturation));
    int q = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - f * saturation));
    int t = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

    if      (hi == 0)  return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
    else if (hi == 1)  return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
    else if (hi == 2)  return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
    else if (hi == 3)  return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
    else if (hi == 4)  return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
    else               return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
}
```

Do note the input ranges!!

Now it is easy to setup a `Color` array at class level:

```
int width = 10;
int height = 9;
Color[,] colors;
```

And fill it:

```
void loadColors()
{
    colors = new Color[width, height];

    // load greys
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++ ) colors[i, 0] = HsvToRgb(0f, 0f, 1f * i / width);
    // load bright stripe:
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) colors[i, 1] = HsvToRgb(i* 360f / width, 0.33f, 1f);
    // load matrix:
    for (int j = 2; j < height; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
             colors[i, j] = HsvToRgb(i * 360f / width, 1f, 1f * (height - j + 2) / height);
}
```

From this is is a snap to set the `BackColors` of your `Panels`.

Here is a `Form.Paint` function, I used to create the above screenshot:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int w = ClientSize.Width / width;
    int h = ClientSize.Height / height;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) 
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[i,j]))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, i * w, j * h, w, h);
        }
}
```

Of course it is as simple as changing two numbers to make a finer grid, here 20x20:

[image]

Also note how the even spacing of hues doesn't really work well, as neither the [human eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) nor our common display systems are equally sensitive to changes in hues across the spectrum..

The eye is actually rather [sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision) to greenish hues

> the just-noticeable difference in wavelength varies from about 1 nm in
>   the blue-green and yellow wavelengths, to 10 nm and more in the longer
>   red and shorter blue wavelengths

but our monitors do a pretty bad job at creating different green hues..

Using an adapted list of [perceptionally evenly spaced hues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munsell_color_system) might help, depending on what you want..

[image]

Using this one-liner:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int hue = (int) ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).GetHue();
}
```

on the image above gives us one such list of hues:

```
20 32 41 50 58 72 133 163 170 177 183 190 197 206 269 288 307 324 334 346
```

I have modified it a little, maybe to make it work better with my monitor:

```
List<int> hues = new List<int> 
{ 20, 32, 41, 50, 58, 72, 133, 162,  180, 188, 195,  205, 215, 223, 246, 267, 288, 300, 320, 346 };
```

And changing the above code (keeping width = 20) to

```
HsvToRgb(hues[i],..
```

results in this:

[image]

Update: I have replaced the `HsvToRgb` function by a greatly simplified one.

Comment: Not the human eye, the display device.  Gamma correction is required.

Comment: Well, both. But wrt to green you are right; changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you, This worked perfectly, I had to change the part where it draws the graphics (e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, i * w, j * h, w, h);) but it wasnt hard at all to get it working. Thank you so much

Comment: Do consider changing the hue-loop to using the numbers at the end of my answer!

Comment: The first post you did worked perfectly and fits my needs perfectly, But I did try your suggestion at the end in a seperate program and Its rather interesting. I had no idea the eye is rather sensitive to greenish hues. Thank you though

Comment: Well, it should be, considering that we had to survive in the jungle and savannah for so long..

Answer (score 2):

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3837824/1838048) you'll get the possibility to use the HSB representation of a color (maybe take also a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106615/1838048)).

By using this you can for the first row use a random hue, a zero saturation and a brightness going from 1.0 to 0.0 in the amount of needed steps. For the other rows you have to take 1.0 for the saturation and increase the hue from 0 to 360 in the same amount of steps and also increase the saturation from 0.0 to 1.0 per row.

I just put an example together:

```
private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateImage(e.Graphics);
}

private void UpdateImage(Graphics graphics)
{
    var columns = 10;
    var rows = 8;

    var hueSteps = 360 / columns;
    var columnSteps = 1.0F / columns;

    var width = Width / columns;
    var height = Height / (rows + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        var gray = ColorExtensions.FromAhsb(255, 0, 0, columnSteps * i);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(gray))
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(brush, width * i, 0, width, height);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++)
        {
            var color = ColorExtensions.FromAhsb(255, hueSteps * i, 1, columnSteps * j);

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, width * i, height * j, width, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is not exact the same, but that would be just a matter of re-arrange the loops:[image: color table]